# Using re.findall to create a link grabber in Python

Tags: python

So I am going to try and create this **scraper** for a friend.
Basically, I want it to take all the links from a website. That's it.

I know it would be somewhat around the lines of:

```
links = re.findall()
print links
```

I found re.finall on the web, but not sure how to use it!
Any pointers in the right direction would help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead. It handles crappy HTML and presents a really nice interface for parsing HTML. Plus, it's really easy to use. Here's your scraper (straight [from the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)):

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks but my dilemma with using that is that I am only testing it with http://labs.codecademy.com/. I have VPS but I don't want to use it for this. Also, my friend won't be able to use that.

Comment: I suggest you download and install Python. [It's not hard](http://www.python.org/download/), and you might already have it. Plus, codeacademy isn't going to be good for testing a link grabber anyway since it's not going to have access to foreign URLs. If your friend really can't install Python and BeautifulSoup, you can give him a prebuilt program with `py2app` or `py2exe`.